# SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint2 013 farm in same DNS

Tags: dns

Is it possible to have two farms on the same DNS?
And if so, is there any documentation out there how to get this working the right way?

We are basically upgrading from 2010 tot 2013 and some pages require testing.

Comment: By DNS do you mean having the same hostname for both farms. Hostname = A NAME record on your DNS.

Comment: Well yes, but thats obv?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have a different SharePoint under the same hostname (AAAA) for instance: http://www.mysharepoint.com. The answer is no.

But if you configure as the different sub-domain for instance: http://site2010.mysharepoint.com and the other   http://site2013.mysharepoint.com
That is possible.

Comment: Sorry, i edited Radityo his answer.

If http://website.com exsist already. If its possible to create http://2013.website.com, and have some of the old sitecollections redirect to http://2013.website.com/page?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by redirect old site. Practically designed that way. You can only use 1 DNS with 1 web application. Can't be more than that.